# Access denied on API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I tried to install API Manager on an Amazon EC2 service, the installation didn't return an error but when I launch the service via a bash, it does give me some :

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /home/ec2-user/wso2am-1.10.0
Using Java memory options: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
[2016-02-05 14:24:27,851]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2016-02-05 14:24:27,860]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System : Linux 4.1.13-19.31.amzn1.x86_64, amd64
[2016-02-05 14:24:27,860]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home        : /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_11/jre
[2016-02-05 14:24:27,860]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version     : 1.8.0_11
[2016-02-05 14:24:27,860]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.11-b03,Oracle Corporation
[2016-02-05 14:24:27,860]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home      : /home/ec2-user/wso2am-1.10.0
[2016-02-05 14:24:27,861]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir    : /home/ec2-user/wso2am-1.10.0/tmp
[2016-02-05 14:24:27,861]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User             : ec2-user, fr-FR, Zulu
[2016-02-05 14:24:28,094]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter Swap Memory size (MB): 0 of the system is below the recommended minimum size :2047
[2016-02-05 14:24:28,097]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter Maximum PermGen space (MB) :0 of the running JVM is set below the recommended minimum size :256
[2016-02-05 14:24:28,097]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter Carbon is configured to use the default keystore (wso2carbon.jks). To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
[2016-02-05 14:24:28,097]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter RAM size (MB): 995 of the system is below the recommended minimum size :2047
[2016-02-05 14:24:28,252]  INFO - AgentHolder Agent created !
[2016-02-05 14:24:28,295]  INFO - AgentDS Successfully deployed Agent Client
[2016-02-05 14:24:33,716]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Configured Registry in 155ms
[2016-02-05 14:24:33,826]  INFO - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
[2016-02-05 14:24:34,265]  INFO - MetricServiceImpl Creating JDBC reporter for Metrics with source 'ip-172-31-19-177.eu-central-1.compute.internal', data source 'jdbc/WSO2MetricsDB' and 60 seconds polling period
[2016-02-05 14:24:34,266]  INFO - AbstractReporter Started JMX reporter for Metrics
[2016-02-05 14:24:34,283]  INFO - AbstractReporter Started JDBC reporter for Metrics
[2016-02-05 14:24:38,558]  INFO - SolrClient Default Embedded Solr Server Initialized
[2016-02-05 14:24:39,117]  INFO - UserStoreMgtDSComponent Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[2016-02-05 14:24:49,170]  INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
[2016-02-05 14:24:50,312]  INFO - ClusterBuilder Clustering has been disabled
[2016-02-05 14:24:50,629]  INFO - UserStoreConfigurationDeployer User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[2016-02-05 14:24:50,630]  INFO - UserStoreConfigurationDeployer User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[2016-02-05 14:24:50,667]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSender Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender...
[2016-02-05 14:24:50,727]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSender Pass-through HTTP Sender started...
[2016-02-05 14:24:50,727]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender...
[2016-02-05 14:24:50,731]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading Identity Keystore from : repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks
[2016-02-05 14:24:50,734]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading Trust Keystore from : repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
[2016-02-05 14:24:50,747]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender Pass-through HTTPS Sender started...
[2016-02-05 14:24:50,762]  INFO - PassThroughHttpListener Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Listener...
[2016-02-05 14:24:50,807]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLListener Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Listener...
[2016-02-05 14:24:50,931]  INFO - ModuleDeployer Deploying module: addressing-1.6.1-wso2v16 - file:/home/ec2-user/wso2am-1.10.0/repository/deployment/client/modules/addressing-1.6.1-wso2v16.mar
[2016-02-05 14:24:53,313]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.message.processor-4.5.1 - 
[2016-02-05 14:24:53,332]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.message.store-4.5.1 - 
[2016-02-05 14:24:53,937]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.registry.ws.api-4.4.8 - 
[2016-02-05 14:24:55,011]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Repository       : /home/ec2-user/wso2am-1.10.0/repository/deployment/server/
[2016-02-05 14:24:55,611]  INFO - TenantLoadingConfig Using tenant lazy loading policy...
[2016-02-05 14:24:55,621]  INFO - PermissionUpdater Permission cache updated for tenant -1234
[2016-02-05 14:24:56,288]  INFO - DefaultKeyValidationHandler org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler Initialised
[2016-02-05 14:24:56,291]  INFO - APIKeyValidationService Initialised KeyValidationHandler instance successfully
[2016-02-05 14:24:56,292]  INFO - APIKeyMgtServiceComponent Setting default carbon host for thrift key management service: 172.31.19.177
[2016-02-05 14:24:56,451]  INFO - APIKeyMgtServiceComponent Started thrift key mgt service at port:10397
[2016-02-05 14:24:56,555]  INFO - SessionDataStore Thread pool size for session persistent consumer : 100
[2016-02-05 14:24:56,724]  INFO - SessionDataStore Session Data Operations CleanUp Task of Authentication framework is not enabled.
[2016-02-05 14:24:56,908]  INFO - ServiceBusInitializer Starting ESB...
[2016-02-05 14:24:56,933]  INFO - ServiceBusInitializer Initializing Apache Synapse...
[2016-02-05 14:24:56,939]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using Synapse home : /home/ec2-user/wso2am-1.10.0/.
[2016-02-05 14:24:56,944]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using synapse.xml location : /home/ec2-user/wso2am-1.10.0/././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
[2016-02-05 14:24:56,944]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using server name : localhost
[2016-02-05 14:24:56,951]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory The timeout handler will run every : 15s
[2016-02-05 14:24:56,967]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Initializing Synapse at : Fri Feb 05 14:24:56 UTC 2016
[2016-02-05 14:24:56,975]  INFO - CarbonSynapseController Loading the mediation configuration from the file system
[2016-02-05 14:24:56,981]  INFO - MultiXMLConfigurationBuilder Building synapse configuration from the synapse artifact repository at : ././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
[2016-02-05 14:24:56,987]  INFO - XMLConfigurationBuilder Generating the Synapse configuration model by parsing the XML configuration
[2016-02-05 14:24:57,069]  INFO - SchemaBuilder XACML policy schema loaded successfully.
[2016-02-05 14:24:57,233]  INFO - SynapseConfigurationBuilder Loaded Synapse configuration from the artifact repository at : ././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
[2016-02-05 14:24:57,237]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Loading mediator extensions...
[2016-02-05 14:24:58,206]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: echo {super-tenant}
[2016-02-05 14:24:58,215]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: Echo.aar - file:/home/ec2-user/wso2am-1.10.0/repository/deployment/server/axis2services/Echo.aar
[2016-02-05 14:24:58,232]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: Version {super-tenant}
[2016-02-05 14:24:58,232]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: Version.aar - file:/home/ec2-user/wso2am-1.10.0/repository/deployment/server/axis2services/Version.aar
[2016-02-05 14:25:00,675]  INFO - TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/am/sample/calculator/v1].File[/home/ec2-user/wso2am-1.10.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/am#sample#calculator#v1.war]
[2016-02-05 14:25:04,235]  INFO - ServerImpl Setting the server's publish address to be /
[2016-02-05 14:25:04,377]  INFO - TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api/am/publisher/v0.9].File[/home/ec2-user/wso2am-1.10.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/api#am#publisher#v0.9.war]
[2016-02-05 14:25:08,067]  INFO - ServerImpl Setting the server's publish address to be /
[2016-02-05 14:25:08,195]  INFO - TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api/am/store/v0.9].File[/home/ec2-user/wso2am-1.10.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/api#am#store#v0.9.war]
[2016-02-05 14:25:08,584]  INFO - TenantDataManager EndpointConfig.properties file loaded from ./repository/conf/identity/EndpointConfig.properties
[2016-02-05 14:25:09,611]  INFO - TldLocationsCache At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2016-02-05 14:25:11,292]  INFO - TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/authenticationendpoint].File[/home/ec2-user/wso2am-1.10.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint.war]
[2016-02-05 14:25:14,232]  INFO - ServerImpl Setting the server's publish address to be /register
[2016-02-05 14:25:14,363]  INFO - TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/client-registration/v0.9].File[/home/ec2-user/wso2am-1.10.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/client-registration#v0.9.war]
[2016-02-05 14:25:17,619]  INFO - TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/oauth2].File[/home/ec2-user/wso2am-1.10.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/oauth2.war]
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,001]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deploying the Synapse service...
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,002]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deploying Proxy services...
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,002]  INFO - ProxyService Building Axis service for Proxy service : WorkflowCallbackService
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,019]  INFO - ProxyService Adding service WorkflowCallbackService to the Axis2 configuration
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,021]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: WorkflowCallbackService {super-tenant}
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,021]  INFO - ProxyService Successfully created the Axis2 service for Proxy service : WorkflowCallbackService
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,021]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deployed Proxy service : WorkflowCallbackService
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,021]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deploying EventSources...
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,047]  INFO - API Initializing API: _WSO2AMRevokeAPI_
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,047]  INFO - API Initializing API: _WSO2AMAuthorizeAPI_
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,048]  INFO - API Initializing API: _WSO2AMTokenAPI_
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,051]  INFO - API Initializing API: _WSO2AMUserInfoAPI_
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,052]  INFO - ServerManager Server ready for processing...
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,536]  INFO - StatisticsServiceComponent BAM Service Stat Publishing is disabled
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,733]  INFO - PassThroughHttpListener Starting Pass-through HTTP Listener...
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,749]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8280
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,750]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLListener Starting Pass-through HTTPS Listener...
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,756]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8243
[2016-02-05 14:25:19,998]  INFO - NioSelectorPool Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
[2016-02-05 14:25:20,074]  INFO - NioSelectorPool Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
[2016-02-05 14:25:20,298]  INFO - TaskServiceImpl Task service starting in STANDALONE mode...
[2016-02-05 14:25:20,457]  INFO - RegistryEventingServiceComponent Successfully Initialized Eventing on Registry
[2016-02-05 14:25:20,612]  INFO - JMXServerManager JMX Service URL  : service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11111/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi
[2016-02-05 14:25:20,613]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Server           :  WSO2 API Manager-1.10.0
[2016-02-05 14:25:20,614]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent WSO2 Carbon started in 59 sec
[2016-02-05 14:25:21,083]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL  : https://172.31.19.177:9443/carbon/
[2016-02-05 14:25:21,084]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Publisher Default Context : http://172.31.19.177:9763/publisher
[2016-02-05 14:25:21,084]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Store Default Context : http://172.31.19.177:9763/store
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,622] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Feb 05 14:25:19 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,624] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Feb 04 16:02:01 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,623] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Feb 05 14:25:19 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,626] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Feb 04 16:02:01 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,623] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Feb 05 14:25:19 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,627] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Feb 04 16:02:01 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,623] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Feb 05 14:25:19 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,622] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Feb 05 14:25:19 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,628] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Feb 04 16:02:01 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,622] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Feb 05 14:25:19 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,635] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Feb 04 16:02:01 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,622] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Feb 05 14:25:19 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,636] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Feb 04 16:02:01 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,622] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Feb 05 14:25:19 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,636] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Feb 04 16:02:01 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,622] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Feb 05 14:25:19 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,636] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Feb 04 16:02:01 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,622] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Feb 05 14:25:19 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,636] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Feb 04 16:02:01 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,627] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Feb 04 16:02:01 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,751] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Feb 05 14:24:50 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,751] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Feb 04 16:01:33 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,753] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Feb 05 14:25:19 UTC 2016"
[2016-02-05 14:25:41,754] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Feb 04 16:02:01 UTC 2016"
```

And after a while nothing happens, I quit :

```
^C
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,025]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Shutdown hook triggered....
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,026]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Gracefully shutting down WSO2 API Manager...
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,032]  INFO - ServerManagement Starting to switch to maintenance mode...
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,032]  INFO - PassThroughHttpListener Stopping Pass-through HTTP Listener..
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,033]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Shutting down IO Reactor bind for port 8280
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,035]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher Listener shutdown.
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,035]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLListener Stopping Pass-through HTTPS Listener..
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,036]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Shutting down IO Reactor bind for port 8243
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,036]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher Listener shutdown.
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,037]  INFO - ServerManagement Stopped all transport listeners
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,037]  INFO - ServerManagement Waiting for request service completion...
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,042]  INFO - ServerManagement All requests have been served.
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,042]  INFO - ServerManagement Waiting for deployment completion...
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,108]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api/am/publisher/v0.9]
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,138]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/oauth2]
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,165]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/authenticationendpoint]
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,189]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/client-registration/v0.9]
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,209]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/am/sample/calculator/v1]
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,230]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api/am/store/v0.9]
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,240]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/workflow-admin]
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,244]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/store]
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,251]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/admin-dashboard]
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,260]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/publisher]
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,260]  INFO - ServerManagement All deployment tasks have been completed.
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,260]  INFO - ServerManagement Waiting for server task completion...
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,301]  INFO - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Writing logs 
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,303]  INFO - ServerManagement All server tasks have been completed.
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,303]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Shutting down WSO2 API Manager...
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,303]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Shutting down OSGi framework...
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,404]  INFO - SynapseTaskManager Shutting down the task manager
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,460]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Stopping CarbonServerManager...
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,462]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSender HTTP Sender shutdown
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,462]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender HTTPS Sender shutdown
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,462]  INFO - PassThroughHttpListener Destroying PassThroughHttpListener
[2016-02-05 14:29:15,463]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLListener Destroying PassThroughHttpListener
[2016-02-05 14:29:17,748]  INFO - CarbonTomcatServiceComponent Stopping the carbon web-app registered under : /
[2016-02-05 14:29:17,794]  INFO - AbstractReporter Stopped JMX reporter for Metrics
[2016-02-05 14:29:17,795]  INFO - AbstractReporter Stopped JDBC reporter for Metrics
[2016-02-05 14:29:18,461]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Shutdown complete
[2016-02-05 14:29:18,461]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Halting JVM
```

I tried to connect to the server using the port 9443 but I just got an ACCESS DENIED page.

Do you guys have an idea where did my installation or my configuration gone wrong ?

Notice that in the installation tutorial, this command didn't worked :

```
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

Thanks you for your help,
Jérémy

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be known issue and reported [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-2904) and [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-2977), as a workaround set you system locale to English.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your reply, sorry for being so late to answer. Does this prevent WSO2 Carbon to display the webinterface on http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9443/carbon ?

Or is there something else ? I'll update Governance Registry and see what happens.