# WSO2 API Manager Issue Unparseable date

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

when i try to view the api response time i get this error on my wso2 api anager console :

```
[2016-02-19 16:06:09,890] ERROR - SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Feb 19 11:55:24 CET 2016"
```

Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access denied on API Manager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35227176/access-denied-on-api-manager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know issue and reported [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-2904). As a workaround, you can change the locale to English and try